# compare img src + a wrap url strings to see if they are "similar"

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have the following code:

```
    <div class="container">

        <a href="http://testing.test/photo.jpg">
            <img src="http://testing.test/photo.jpg">
        </a>

        <a href="http://testing.test/photo.jpg">
            <img src="http://testing.test/photo-450x450.jpg">
        </a>

        <a href="http://testing.test/photo.jpg">
            <img src="http://testing.test/photo-150x150.jpg">
        </a>

        <a href="http://somethingdifferent.test">
            <img src="http://testing.test/photo.jpg">
        </a>

    </div>
```

I am trying to add a class to the A tags with images inside.

So  I have

```
$(".container").find('a').has("img").each(function () {

            $(this).addClass("testingClass");
    });
```

However, now I want to add an extra check. I want to add the class ONLY if the image src + a href wrapping it are the same or "similar" (they only have the thumbnail size at the end i.e -150x150).

In other words, in the HTML code above, it would add the class to `<a>` 1,2,3 but not 4.

How can I do this in Javascript/jQuery? For the first a tag, I could simply compare the src value and href value, and if identical = then true/add class. But the others aren't stricly the same and would turn out false, is there a way to do it?

Thanks guys for any tips

Comment: You'd use a regexp. Not exactly sure what you want to match, so not sure how to write a regex for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to condense it but in retrospect it may be difficult to read so I'll try to walk through it below:

```
$(".container").find('a').has("img").each(function(){
    var f1 = $(this).attr('href').split('/').slice(-1)[0].split('.'),
        f2 = $(this).find('img:first').attr('src').split('/').slice(-1)[0],
        re = new RegExp('^'+f1.slice(0,f1.length-1).join('.')
             +'(?:-\\d+?x\\d+?)?\\.'+f1.slice(-1)[0]+'$');
    if(re.test(f2)) $(this).addClass("testingClass");
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Npt2J/)

Basically I'm grabbing the last part of the `href` and the `src` values, spliting up the `href` into two parts (the file name and the file extension) and building a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) on the fly to match either the exact name or the file name with the suffix `-\dx\d` where `\d` represents any digit.

To better visualise it, the [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (important bit) reads as follows:

```
/^FILE_NAME(?:-\d+?x\d+?)?\.FILE_EXT$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work without regex:

```
$(".container a").has("img").each(function () {
    var hURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var iURL = $(this).children("img").attr("src");

    var imgName = iURL.slice(iURL.lastIndexOf("/")+1,iURL.lastIndexOf("."));

    var hrefPointer = hURL.slice(hURL.lastIndexOf("/")+1,hURL.lastIndexOf("."));

    if(imgName.indexOf(hrefPointer) >= 0 && hrefPointer.length > 1) {
       $(this).addClass("testingClass");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9EZ/1/)

**Note:** This is sloppy, and a better idea would be to have a clearly defined "similarity" that you search for via a regular expression. Define a pattern, and match the pattern, it's much better than a coincidental analysis of strings.

For example should they only match if they're from the same domain? Same full path

```
http://test.test.test/photo.jpg == 
http://test.test.test/thumbnails/photo-150x150.jpg
```

?

What about extensions? Does

```
http://test.test.test/photo.jpg == 
http://test.test.test/photo-150x150.png
```

It's tough to define a function without its tests. For more info on that, take a look at the ideas of [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Hope this helps on this and future projects.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip the extension from the href and test if it's the prefix of the image url (if this satisfies your definition of "is similar"):

```
jQuery(".container a img").each(function () {
    var href_url = jQuery(this).parent("a").attr("href");
    var img_url = jQuery(this).attr("src");

    if(img_url.indexOf(href_url.substring(0, href_url.lastIndexOf("."))) == 0) {
       jQuery(this).parent("a").addClass("testingClass");
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Fixed the original code to add class the `a` tag and replaced `startsWith` with `indexOf == 0`, since there is no `startsWith` in javascript. The [working example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvzaz/1/).

Comment: that would add the class to the `img`, not the `a`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, this would add it to the `img` (I took this from the original question, I haven't noticed he wants to class a). To add to `a` it would be `jQuery(this).parent("a").addClass...` (of course, the the parent could be stored to a var in the first usage).

Comment: Thanks, but I tested this on a few different values (different href url, to something that isn't an image) and it doesn't always work. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/bvzaz/2/

Comment: It depends on how robust solution you need, I assumed that the initial selector returns only the cases which are more less relevant. If not, then the test has to be more precise. Like: [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvzaz/5/) which tests for image extensions in the href (the `/i` at the en of regexp means case insensitive).